# How do I tell my app to rotate -90º for a specific monitor which doesn't report orientation?

Tags: user-interface, display, television

I need to place some content on a TV screen. The TV is vertically placed and agnostic of it's orientation. The best way for me is to use HTML, CSS and JS for animations.

How do I tell the whole viewport should rotate -90º?

Or is this not possible using HTML?

Thanks in advance!

I've tried @media queries orientation property, but the screen is agnostic of its orientation

Comment: rotate the display at the OS level

Comment: I'm guessing the web page will be rendered on the TV directly (nothing plugged into the TV)? Otherwise it would be far simpler to configure rotation for the video output on the device that the web browser will be running on.

Comment: Wouldn't know how to..

Comment: Yes, there will be a "player" as client call it. You're probably right. I'll check out that player.